# Cross-installation importing of Python libraries

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo

I have installed Anaconda because it supports [Pyomo](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyomo) and I also have installed WinPython for pip installing libraries like [TspLib95](https://tsplib95.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/usage.html) whose pip installation gives Anaconda hickups.

I now want to use Pyomo and TspLib95 in combination by somehow importing the WinPython TspLib95 library into an Anaconda project.

**Question:**  python
Does Python allow such 'cross breeding', resp., is there anything that comes close to it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You should try installing both on the same interpreter.

Comment: @wRAR I have tried to install both on the same interpreter, which didn't work; therefore I posted the question...

Comment: I understand this, I meant trying to fix those problems is AFAIK the only way to go.

Comment: Why aren't you just using pip for both?  Both packages say they are pip-installable.  I only use pip for pyomo, and the TSPLIB95 dox say it is pip capable.

Comment: @AirSquid using pip for installing TSPLib95 under Anaconda tends to mess up existing installations; I have already tried that and had to roll back everything. Installing Pyomo under WinPython fails because one also needs to install solvers like GLPK which tends to entangle you in configuration hell. I have really tried a lot of things without success.

Comment: caveat:  I don't use Conda anymore and I'm on MacOS, and WinPython appears to be yet another distribution manager...  That said, are you using Conda's virtual environment capability for TSPLib to keep it from "messing up existing installations?"  You might try switching over to "pip land" to see if you like it unless you have other reasons for Conda.  You could make a fake new user on your machine (clean environ), install python, use venv module to make venv, pip pyomo and TSPLib and use windows procedure for getting a solver like CBC.

Comment: @AirSquid thanks for the hint to the venv; I'll give it another try...